# Coletar link da imagem com python , selenium e webdriver

Tags: python, url, selenium-webdriver

Preciso rodar um script em python para pegar a url de uma imagem que só é mostrada apos rodar o javascript da pagina. Estou utilizando python3 com selenium e webdriver. Porem ao tentar localizar o link e printar esta com erro.
Segue print do html e script usado.

```
    import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

chromedriver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
chromium_path = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"

service = service.Service(chromedriver_path)
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': chromium_path}
opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = chromium_path

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
driver.get('http://IP/devices/')
timeout = 20
image = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(("//img")
print(image, '\n')
```

[image: codigo htlm]

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano, o `find_elements_by_xpath` retorna uma lista de todos os elementos que obedecem o xpath. 
Tente usar o `find_element_by_xpath` passando o xpath usando o ID, assim: `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id = 'imgcap']")` ou use o método que já busca direto pelo ID: `find_element_by_id`.

OBS.: Neste caso, se você passar só `//img` no xpath, ele retornará o primeiro nó que seja do tipo img.